# Can't push to github

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push a branch (named "grails-1.3") to my github repo. Here's what's happening

```
> git push origin grails-1.3
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

This is the first time I've ever tried to push to my git repo, so I guess I don't have username/password/SSH setup properly. My `.git/config` file contains the following:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = ssh://git@github.com/domurtag/airbrake-grails.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

### Update

I had a look in the "SSH Keys" section of my GitHub account and it says:

> There are no SSH keys with access to your account.

Comment: You have to look at your public keys registered in github. Either your key is wrong or the key you are using is not registered.

Answer (score 2):

Have you configured SSH it github to use your public RSA key? And have you made an RSA key? Have a look halfway down here:

https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey

If you're using an IDE like Eclipse, you can make the key there through Preferences->General->Network Connections->SSH2. There you can see where the keys are stored locally, and under the Key Management tab you can create a new key. Once you generate the new key, copy the key text as-is into your github account (Github->Account Settings->SSH Keys).

Here it all is from the command line:

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Answer (score 2):

You have to generate a rsa key pair:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

and then register the fingerprint of you public key on github.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on [Windows](http://windows.github.com/) (or [MacOS](http://mac.github.com/), but haven't tried that on my own), I highly recommend installing the official GitHub client even if you intend to stick to the command line.

The client sets up everything correctly like SSH keys and initial clone of your repo. It also comes with a nice shell integration so that you can see directly on the shell whether some files are outdated, etc.